# Unity: How Do I Center A Mouse To A 3D Player Using Vector3.MoveTowards()?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mouse-position

I am currently using mouse inputs to move a player (sphere) in a 3d world. I am doing this with a raycast and using the `hit.point` coordinates. This is the way I want my game to work, but it is a 3d game, so whenever I move the player, using the mouse coordinates, it won't align properly. This is due to the player being 3d and the mouse coordinates being 2d.

Here is my code:

```
public float speed;
public GameObject player;

private Ray ray;
private RaycastHit hit;
private Vector3 mousePos;

void Start ()
{

}

void FixedUpdate ()
{
    ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

    if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
    {
        mousePos = new Vector3(hit.point.x, /*Insert Code*/, hit.point.z);

        if(mousePos != player.transform.position)
        {
            player.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(player.transform.position, mousePos, speed * Time.deltaTime); 
        }
    }
}
```

My question is this:

If I have the player at 1.3f above the ground, how can I manipulate `Vector3.MoveTowards` so the mouse is centered in the player without affecting the height of the player (1.3f)?

I tried using `player.transform.position.y`, but it placed the mouse directly under the player (the x and z values worked, but the y-value didn't).

I, also, tried hit.point.y, but it gave me values greater than the player height (1.3f).

Comment: Unity question are generally better asked on a Unity/Mono Forum. This Forum is still a better hit then the MSDN one, but not by far.

Comment: @Christopher I usually go here for questions about unity. I'll try there, too.

Comment: `hit.point.y` is probably not returning the value you want because the raycast is hitting the player object. You should use a layermask to exclude the player object from the mouse raycast.

Comment: @Draco18s what is a layermask?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be the best way to solve my issue but it solves it for now. I made a plane with a y value of 1.3f and put it through the player object. I, then, made the object invisible. Now, the raycast will hit that object instead of the ground.